# append input value to a div jquery whilst user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is append to text from a input field to a div as the user is typing...

So they can see what the text will look like.

What I have is the below.

```
jQuery('#options_6_text').keyup(function() {
    jQuery('.product_zoom').appendTo(jQuery(jQuery(this).val()));
    console.log(jQuery(this).val())
});
```

Now the console.log is working as I would have thought, however the text does not seem to be appending to the .product_zoom div, any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
    jQuery('#options_6_text').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    jQuery('.product_zoom').text(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

This allowed me to do exactly what I was after.

Thanks

Comment: `appendTo` insinuates that the previous element will be appended `elsewhere` if you want to append data `to the element` it's just `append()`

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
jQuery('.product_zoom').html(this.value);
```

You're going to want to use `.html()` for this, this way it replaces the div content each time the user types, the `append()` was adding to the current content each time.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rRnSB/

Comment: Yes...but the why....the why is the most important part. Too many people these days trying to poach karma with an instant 1 liner. no explanation. For me, maybe it's just a personal thing, but I'm trying to foster an environment that gives you the how and the why, not just the here.

Comment: Agree, updated the answer with a quick explanation and API references, should help to get on the right path.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks heaps... 

I am actually still having issues with it. I understand why, but not to sure how to fix it. say I'm typing 555 in the box, it displays

555555

Obviously because it keeps adding what I have in the box to the text... Do you know if there is anyway I can have it mirror what it says in the text field?

Thanks.

Comment: @user2417267 -- Changed my answer, realized the mistake once I made a fiddle.

Comment: Hey Thanks, that however doesn't seem to work until the second key is pressed... I was able to fix it by using


 jQuery('#options_6_text').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    jQuery('.product_zoom').text(jQuery(this).val());
});

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing it like this:  **[SIMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rRnSB/1/)**

```
$('#options_6_text').keyup(function() {
    $('.product_zoom').text(this.value);
});
```